# Does the email address always have to be in the donation section on a Contribution Form?

Tags: civicontribute, profile

I tried to add an email address in the "Name and Address" profile, hoping it would remove the email address from up in the donation amounts area (keeping all the contact info in one section). Instead it deleted the email address field from the "Name and Address" profile.

Can I move that email address down somehow?

[image: Email address on contrib page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For contribution forms yes. For event registration pages, the code has been modified to detect if an email address is being recorded in the profile and if so to remove it.

Might be easiest to take a look at the event registration code and see if you can port the relevant code to the contribution side of things

Comment: Thanks Lobo. I found the patch that went into events and will take a peek to see how easy the port would be or if it is beyond my ken.

Comment: I've moved this to the forum for further guidance, anyone who is willing/able! http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36375.0.html

Comment: And on to JIRA: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16339